# How i can find android manifest in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how i can find android manifest and android or ios folder in my react native project ?
these are my folders.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

just you need type ***expo eject*** in your console,  and you can get android folder with android manifest.
[image]

Comment: yes but `expo eject` means you won't be able to go back to using expo

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an android or an ios folder because of you are using expo. when  you are using expo, expo deals with those folders for you, so you don't need to interact with them. but you can eject your application from expo like alireza explained above and get those native folders for your project but if you do this you won't be able to run your project through expo go app. and you will lose some of the expo features along the way.

In this case you only need to access android manifest file you can use `app.json` or `app.config.js` files on your expo project. app.json configures many things, from your app name, app version, app icon to splash screen and even deep linking scheme and API keys to use for some services and app permissions and more. To see a full list of available properties, please refer to the app.json / app.config.js reference.

[Using app.js](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/)

[App.json reference](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/)